# nav bar - help needed

Tags: css, html

How to I add dropdown sub-menus to this nav bar?

I need only one dropdown layer.

I need the sub-menus to be shown with hover over the nav bar in full screen and be hidden (unless the nav bar is clicked) when the screen is reduced to the toggle menu.

I also need to put the nav bar in a ‘container’? or  so that when I type text in the body the text follows after the nav bar and not hidden behind the nav bar.

I need the actual code modified rather than hints.

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content ="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">



<title>Flexbox Dropdown Menu</title>


<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}





</style>
</head>



<body>

<div>
<header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">CSS Nav</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Our Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
</div>

<div>

<p>this is my website content</p>

</div>

</body>



<script>

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome!  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi. I need some kind of .submenu class for the submenu. I tried putting <header> inside a <div>, but did not work.

Comment: For this, if you don't want to use Bootstrap, or any framework for that matter, you have to learn JavaScript or get into unnecessarily complex CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap framework which will make this easy for you to implement a navbar and the rest of the containers.

Here's the link of the official website:

[Bootstrap Website](https://getbootstrap.com/)

And here is the Bootstrap's navbar component implementation:

[Navbar component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/)

It matches with what you want, a dropdown on larger screens and a toggle menu in mobile.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking to modify the code that I posted.

Comment: I am not familiar with bootstrap. It says that there may still be overlap requiring css - so I am no further at answering that question.

Comment: You only need to call the "CSS" in the <head> and the "js" at bottom of your HTML. Next, all you have to do is to learn the classes and how to use them, but you can copy the navbar from the website.

Comment: This is just an easy way, if it is too much problem i'll help you make the dropdown.